# Displaying images JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've tried running this code a lot of times. Images are not even getting loaded. Can I get a good reason for that? html file and images are saved in the same directory and there are two images.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
delay = 200;
image_seq = new Array();
for (i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
    image_seq[i] = new image();
    image_seq[i].src = i + ".jpeg"
}
num = 1;

function animate() {
    document.pic_rotate.src = image_seq[num].src;
    num++;
    if (num > 2)
        num = 1;
}

function slow() {
    delay = delay + 25;
    if (delay > 2000)
        delay = 2000;
}

function fast() {
    delay = delay - 25;
    if (delay < 0)
        delay = 0;
}
</script>
<img name="pic_rotate" src="1.jpeg" onLoad="setTimeout('animate()',delay)">
<form>
<input type="button" value="Slow" onClick="slow()">
<input type="button" value="Fast" onClick="fast()">
</form>
```

Comment: I've done it for you on this occasion, but when asking for help, take the time to format your code using consistent, standard indentation. (Ideally, copy and paste your real code -- you use indentation in your real code, right??) You want to make it easy for people to help you.

Comment: Sir, today is my first day writing up JS codes. I'll try to be more clear next. Btw thanks for so much information! :)

Comment: Happy to help. I was able to grab some time to dash off a quick example, I've added it to the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are *lots* of issues with that code, but the main reason you're not seeing images is that this line uses `image` where it should use `Image`:

```
image_seq[i] = new Image();
//                 ^---- Note that this is `I`, not `i` -- capitalization matters
```

Other issues with the code include:

1. You're falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) all over the place, by failing to declare your variables.
2. You're relying on the browser dumping the identifier `pic_rotate` onto `document` because you've given the element a `name` attribute. That's not necessarily reliable. Instead, use an `id` and look up the element explicitly using `document.getElementById`.
3. Your first call to `animate` will just assign the same image to `pic_rotate` that it already has, so you'll seem to have an unusually long delay before the first image arrives.
4. The code using a counter and an array seems unnecessarily complicated just to flip between two images (`1.jpeg` and `2.jpeg`).
5. `new Array()`, while not in any way *wrong*, is better written simply as `[]`.
6. There's no reason to create image elements if you're only going to use their `src` property (what you're doing won't, for instance, prefetch them because you never add the images you're creating to the DOM).
7. Using old DOM0 `onXyz` attributes is again not *wrong*, but generally not best practice.
8. Passing strings into `setTimeout` is poor practice.
9. It's harmless, but there's no reason to put the buttons in a form if you're not submitting the form.

Here's a complete example dealing with the above: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/goquzepo/1) I've stuck with the loop on the theory you probably had more than two images you were planning to use...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="imageContainer">
</div>
<input id="buttonSlow" type="button" value="Slow">
<input id="buttonFast" type="button" value="Fast">
<script>
  // A scoping function to avoid using any globals
  (function() {
    "use strict"; // Improve JavaScript using its new "strict" mode

    // Declare our variables
    var images, index, delay;

    // Our main initialization function
    function init() {
      // Get the image container
      var imageContainer = document.getElementById("imageContainer");

      // Create an array of images
      images = [
        createImage("https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/1d5ac1c9d660351786dc6b3873627c4d?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"),
        createImage("https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ca3e484c121268e4c8302616b2395eb9?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG")
      ];

      // Add our images to the container, with only the first one being visible
      for (index = 0; index < images.length; ++index) {
        if (index > 0) {
          images[index].style.display = "none"; // Even though hidden, will get fetched
        }
        imageContainer.appendChild(images[index]);
      }

      // Set our index to the currently-showing image, and our standard delay
      index = 0;
      delay = 500; // 500ms = half a second

      // Hook up our buttons (look into addEventListener [attachEvent on
      // older IE], but onclick works for this example)
      document.getElementById("buttonSlow").onclick = function() {
        delay = Math.min(delay + 25, 2000); // Don't go past 2000
      };
      document.getElementById("buttonFast").onclick = function() {
        delay = Math.max(delay - 25, 0); // Don't go below 0
      };

      // Start our animation
      setTimeout(animate, delay);
    }

    // A function to create images
    function createImage(src) {
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = src;
      return img;
    }

    // Our animation function
    function animate() {
      images[index].style.display = "none"; // Hides it
      index = (index + 1) % images.length;  // A fancy way to add one and wrap back to 0 if needed
      images[index].style.display = "";     // Shows it

      // Hook up the next animation with our current delay
      setTimeout(animate, delay);
    }

    // Start!
    init();

  })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```